# iOS application monetization

Tags: developer-program

Can developer monetize application like following:

Developer develops application -> rents that application to certain person which pays to the developer monthly/yearly for such service, that application is content updated.

User (that downloads the app) itself is not paying at all anything.

Is this against the Apple monetization guidelines?

Answer (score 1):

You are free to do with the app as you wish. Apple just want a binary that you upload to iTunes Connect — your business model is unrelated.

Apple doesn't prevent you from selling the entire app either ([they even have a tool for it](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html)) and renting the app is equally fine.

Comment: I was worried about Apple reviewing my binary. (Not approving because I get money not through their store).

Comment: @Kyslik Have you had a look through the [App Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html)?

Comment: Do you mean this [pdf](http://photos.appleinsider.com/App%20Store%20Review%20Guidelines%20-%20App%20Store%20Resource%20Centerai.pdf)? Now that I know what I was supposed to look for... I do read now.

Comment: @Kyslik Ah, you don't have a developer account? Yes, that looks like a PDF version of the same content.

Comment: Ye, I am even waiting for new MacBook Pro that has some GPU for baseline price. Plenty of time, I am working on back end now...